# How to print the second number and its position

Tags: python

My task is to write a script which writes the second number in `s` and its position to standard output.

example input:

```
afg 456 gg 677
```

example output:

```
 677 12
```

my code is all correct except for the `print` part - it's printing the first number and its position rather than the second:

```
s = input()
i = 0

while i < len(s) and (s[i] < "0" or "9" < s[i]):
    i = i + 1

if i < len(s):

    j = i
    while j < len(s) and "0" <= s[j] and s[j] <= "9":
        j = j + 1

    print(s[i:j], len(s[0:i]))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The title of your question is too generic, which makes it more difficult for others to find and answer. Can you please make it more specific to the question. Eg "how to determine the positions etc etc"

Comment: Are you allowed to use `re` module and `.index()` method?

Comment: nah were not allowed

Comment: Your code scans through until it finds a number or end of string. What if it were in a loop that executes two times and only prints the number on the second iteration?

Comment: yeah id say that could work

Comment: If your inputs are separated by a space `" "` use can use `split`, then get only numeric ones and return then second.

Comment: `len(s[0:i])` is equivalent to `i + 1`...

Comment: A simple way to extend your _own approach_ would be to add a line at the bottom of your code which changes the starting value of `i` to the end position of your first number string, so simply append a line `i=j` (in your example case, that will be "7" ) and then add the same while loop structure as before.

Comment: @AerysS  is there a way to then get the position of the second occurrence in `split()`?

Comment: No, split returns a list where each element is separated by a separator. For example using `split(" ")` on that input will result in `["afg", "456" ,"gg" ,"677"]`, so it has to check for numbers. It might not be the best way, but is a short way.

Comment: @AerysS where exactly do i add i=j?

Comment: @User505050 I suppose this question was directed at me? After your while loop, if you add `print(i,j)` you will see that i is 4 (i.e. the beginning of your numeric string) and j is 7 (the end of your string). So _after your while loop_, you need to add `i = j` and then copy & paste the same while loop as before so it _starts iterating from 7_ (i.e. where your last numeric string _ended_) and continues to search for the next occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a homework with some limitation? So there is a silly rather educational sample. Just increase the counter `i` and run the same loops again:

```
s = input()
i = 0
j = 0

# looking for the first num
while i < len(s) and (s[i] < "0" or "9" < s[i]): i = i + 1

if i < len(s):
    j = i
    while j < len(s) and "0" <= s[j] and s[j] <= "9":  j = j + 1

# increase counter
i = i + j

# run again for the second num
if i < len(s):
    while i < len(s) and (s[i] < "0" or "9" < s[i]): i = i + 1

    if i < len(s):
        j = i
        while j < len(s) and "0" <= s[j] and s[j] <= "9":  j = j + 1

print(s[i:j], len(s[0:i]))
```

Not for a real life.